# How can I pass a ObjectDataProvider object instance via a button click event; using XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to pass an object instance defined by ObjectDataProvider to my button-click event. I've seen a few posts that suggested using the Tag property on the button to pass the object to the click method, however I get a null object in the click event method.

The following code defines instances of objects using ObjectDataProvider:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ObjectTypes" ObjectType="{x:Type rvcfg:ConfigDataProvider}" MethodName="GetObjectTypes"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Regions" ObjectType="{x:Type rvcfg:ConfigDataProvider}" MethodName="GetRegionObjects"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Caches" ObjectType="{x:Type rvcfg:ConfigDataProvider}" MethodName="GetCacheObjects"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

The following code defines the button; through which I'm trying to pass the "ObjectTypes" object that is modified in a ListView control.

```
    <Button Content="Save" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="410,293,0,0"               Name="btnSave" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnSave_Click" Tag="{Binding Source=ObjectTypes}"/>
```

The ObjectTypes object contains three string enumerators and a custom ENUM.  I'd appreciate any guidance as to how I can pass this object to my click event method.

Thanks,
KBW

Comment: Won't it be two different instances?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be `Tag="{StaticResource ObjectTypes}"` or `Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource ObjectTypes}}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to use a `Command` with a `CommandParameter`, rather than the Click event with a Tag.

```
<Button Command="Built_In_Or_Custom_Command" CommandParameter="{StaticResource ObjectTypes}" />
```